# Retrieving users from Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve my users name from my Firebase database and then make the "label" in my view controller present that name of the person I am retrieving from the database. been having a hard time with this, does anyone know how I can do this?

thank you!!!

This is the code I found online and was playing around with but had no luck with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users2").document("first name").getDocument { (document, Error) in
            
            //check for error
            if Error == nil {
                //check if document exists
                if document != nil && document!.exists {
                    
                    let documentData = document!.data()
                    
                    let Label.text = ... 
                }
                
                
            }
        }
```

I use Cloud Firestore to store my users info
and the collection is "users2" and then in the document its just the users  first and last name and the uid which is equal to the document ID.
I dont know how to retrieve the the first name and then make my label present it in another view

Comment: It would help us out if you could provide code, and the structure of your database!

Comment: ahh ok will do that now thank you Marcus!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is now trying to load a document with ID `first name`, which likely doesn't exist. Since you say that the document ID is the UID, that should be:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if user != nil {
    db.collection("users2").document(user.uid).getDocument { (document, Error) in
        if Error == nil {
            if document != nil && document!.exists {
                let documentData = document!.data()
                let Label.text = documentData["first name"]
            }
        }
        ...
```